# Replaced windows 8 with ubuntu. All partitions deleted

Tags: windows, windows-8, data-recovery

I installed Ubuntu using live cd by selecting Replace Windows 8 with Ubuntu. I want to get my data back.My windows partition details:

c: 40GB
d: 110GB
c: 160GB
e: 130GB

So shall I reinstall windows 8 and run some recovery software?

Comment: Isn't Ubuntu working fine?

Comment: In case anyone still reads this: it is a bug in the wording of our installer. http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/08/ubuntu-installer-bug-wipes-partitions

Answer (score 1):

You have chosen the replace Ubuntu with Windows 8, this formats the entire partition table of Windows and creates new partitions for Ubuntu which includes '\','\Home' and 'swap'. So reinstalling Windows 8 and running a recovery 'll not fix the problem.